# JAVA: Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Confirming2_App

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

He realizado una aplicación GUI java con Swing y Netbeans. Puedo ejecutarla sin problemas desde Netbeans o desde consola dentro del directorio de la aplicación, sin embargo al llevar el .jar a otro directorio (por ejemplo el escritorio) me sale el error del título de esta pregunta. También he intentado convertir el .jar a .exe mediante Launch4j pero me vuelve a salir el mismo error, en este caso el .jar si lo obtengo del directorio de la aplicación.

¿Alguien sabe a qué se puede deber?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tienes que indicar cual es la clase principal en el archivo Manifest -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: Con ese tutorial me sale el mismo error

Comment: Podría ser un problema de paths. Ojo no estés usando rutas absolutas en lugar de rutas relativas a la ubicación del proyecto.

Comment: Encontre esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498047/export-jar-with-netbeans en SO, yo lo intente con un proyecto pequeño y me funciono.

Comment: Intenta compilarlo con dependencias, puedes ver como hacerlo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta compilarlo con dependencias, aqui esta un codigo tomado de [how do i compile a java file that has jar dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091733/how-do-i-compile-a-java-file-that-has-jar-dependencies)

Para windows:

```
javac -cp ".;/dir/commons.jar;/dir/more_jar_files.jar" MyClass.java
```

Para unix or mac

```
javac -cp ".:/dir/commons.jar:/dir/more_jar_files.jar" MyClass.java
```

Uso

```
javac -cp <ruta al jar> MyClass.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por vuestras aportaciones, al final el error estaba en que Netbeans no incluye al compilar las librerías externas. En este tutorial podéis ver los pasos que he seguido:

http://programandoointentandolo.com/2013/04/crear-archivo-jar-en-netbeans-con-librerias-externas.html